# No query results for model [App\Models\ProductCategory

Tags: laravel-8

I keep getting `No query results for model \[App\\Models\\ProductCategory` error in laravel 9. I have product blade which is used for capturing product items including category which is a drop down that pulls data from ProductCategory. I also have create quotation blade which is used for creating new quotation. Everytime Everytime I try to create new quotation item., I get the afore mentioned error.
I have "products" table which has a column "category_id"; And “ProductCategory” table which has both “category_id” and “category_name”.

My controllers are as follows:

```
    class ProductCategoryController extends AccountBaseController
    {
        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            $this->categories = ProductCategory::all();
            return view('products.category.create', $this->data);
        }
        /**
         * @param StoreProductCategory $request
         * @return array
         * @throws \Ec\RestAPI\Exceptions\RelatedResourceNotFoundException
         */
        public function store(StoreProductCategory $request)
        {
            $category = new ProductCategory();
            $category->category_name = $request->category_name;
            $category->save();
    
            $categories = ProductCategory::get();
            $options = BaseModel::options($categories, $category, 'category_name');
            return Reply::successWithData(__('messages.categoryAdded'), ['data' => $options]);
        }
```

```
//And ProductController:
```

```
class ProductController extends AccountBaseController { 
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();`
    $this->pageTitle = 'app.menu.products';
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
    in_array('client', user_roles()) ? abort_403(!(in_array('orders', $this->user->modules) && user()->permission('add_order') == 'all')) : abort_403(!in_array('products', $this->user->modules));
    
                return $next($request);
            });
        }
        
        /**
         * @param ProductsDataTable $dataTable
         * @return mixed|void
         */
        public function index(ProductsDataTable $dataTable) {
            $viewPermission = user()->permission('view_product');
            abort_403(!in_array($viewPermission, ['all', 'added']));
            $productDetails = [];
            if (request()->hasCookie('productDetails')) {
                $productDetails = json_decode(request()->cookie('productDetails'), true);
            }
            $this->productDetails = $productDetails;
            $this->totalProducts = Product::count();
            $this->categories = ProductCategory::all();
            $this->subCategories = ProductSubCategory::all();`
        
            return $dataTable->render('products.index', $this->data);
```

And Quotation view blade:

````
    \<td class="border-bottom-0"\>\<input type="hidden" id="category" name="category\[\]" value="{{ $items-\>category-\>category_id }}"\>{{ $items-\>category-\>title }}\</td\>```
````

Comment: This is wrong: `ProductCategory::get();`. Paste your error with its entire stacktrace to find out what else is wrong

Comment: Thanks UnderDog. The only error I am seeing in storage\log is: [2023-07-29 12:49:08] code.ERROR: The "--columns" option does not exist. {"exception":"[object] {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): The \"--columns\" option does not exist. Double checking if there is any column missing

Comment: QUnderDog, Surprisingly there is no column missing. And what is wrong with ProductCategory::get();